# moment returns wrong value

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm parsing a date using `momentjs`:

```
var startDate = moment.utc('2016-02-20T07:00:00.000Z')
```

If I'm writing `startDate.toISOString()` to the console, I get this:

```
2016-02-19T21:00:00.000Z
```

The `startDate` object looks like this:

```
{ [Number: 1455915600000]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '2016-02-20T07:00:00.000Z',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ',
  _tzm: -0,
  _isUTC: true,
  _pf: 
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -1,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: true },
  _locale: 
   Locale {
     _ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
     ordinal: [Function],
     _abbr: 'en',
     _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _d: Fri Feb 19 2016 22:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
  _isValid: true,
  _offset: 0 }
```

Where does this difference result from?

Comment: can it be because of the difference in the timezone of your browser? https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/3556/

Comment: It's node.js and the timezome on the machine is CET.

Comment: That's weird, I just tried on my computer (EET timezone) and I see the original date. I have moment@2.11.2 and node v5.5.0. 
Maybe you should upgrade your moment.js version?

Comment: Found it. I'm doing a ```var x = startDate.subtract(10, 'hours')```. Didn't know this modifies the value of ```startDate``` as well instead of only returning a new date.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler If you need to subtract from startDate without changing itself use `moment(startDate).substract(10,'hours')`

Comment: @SaiRam That's what I did as a workaround, thanks anyway :)